# How to find the Rate of Change?

Tags: calculus

Could anyone explain to me the process of this problem? My book tells me to find an related equation and then take the derivative of that in respect to time.

[image: Plane]

**Update**—Thanks for your help Mark!

So the correct method was

> $tan(\theta) = \frac yx$
>
> $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$[tan(\theta) = \frac yx]$ = $sec^2(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ = $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}x - \frac{dx}{dt}y}{x^2}$
>
> Substitute in $-700$ (distance between viewer and airplane decreases with time) for  $\frac{dx}{dt}$, $4$ for $y$, $0$ for $\frac{dy}{dt}$.
>
> The value of $x$ is obtainable by plugging in $45°, 60°, 75°$ for $tan(\theta)$ = $\frac yx$.
>
> The new equation is now $sec^2(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ = $\frac{0x - (-700)4}{x^2}$ or simply $sec^2(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ = $\frac{2800}{x^2}$.
>
> $\frac {d\theta}{dt} = \frac{\frac{2800}{x^2}}{sec^2(\theta)}$ = $\frac{2800}{x^2sec^2(\theta)}$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a right triangle. In this case, we are given the height (call it $y$), and we know that $y = 4$ miles. We also know the rate at which the base of the triangle (call it $x$) is changing with respect to time, namely $\frac{dx}{dt} = -700$ (it's negative because it's causing the base of the triangle to become smaller). You can relate the angle $\theta$ to $x$ and $y$ using trigonometric functions. You will have an equation that relates $\theta$ to the height $y$ and the base $x$. Then take the derivative of both sides with respect to time, plug in the values you are given, and solve. Note: you will be solving for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, the rate at which the angle $\theta$ is changing. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: The trigonometric equation I used was tan $\theta = \frac{y}{x}$. The derivative of that is $[sec^2 \theta](\frac{d\theta}{dt}) = \frac{(\frac{dx}{dt})y-x(\frac{dy}{dt})}{x^2}$. Presumably, if $\theta = 45°$, then both $y$ and $x$ will equal $4$. I can plug these values back into the equation. The only question is 'what is $\frac{dy}{dt}$'?

Comment: One correction: the right-hand side after you take the derivative should be $\frac{x\frac{dy}{dt} - y \frac{dx}{dt}}{x^2}$. To answer your question:  How does the height of the airplane change over time?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't see that earlier—makes sense now since the distance between the viewer and the plane decreases. The height of the airplane, stays constant (?) and therefore is $0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The height of the airplane is constant at 4 miles, so it is not a function of time, so $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$.

Comment: So I calculated the answers through $[sec^2 \theta](\frac{d\theta}{dt}) = \frac{x\frac{dy}{dt} - y \frac{dx}{dt}}{x^2}$. At 45°, $[sec^2 45°](\frac{d\theta}{dt}) = \frac{x(0) - 4(700)}{4^2}$ | $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = -87.5$ rad/min. Is this the correct answer or do I have to account for the hour -> minute conversion rate?

Comment: Yeah, you should probably convert it to minutes.

Comment: Hm.. $[sec^2 45°](\frac{d\theta}{dt}) = \frac{x(0) - 4(\frac{700}{60})}{4^2}$ | $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = -5250$ rad/min. And then for 60° and 75°, I would use tan $\theta = \frac{y}{x}$ to find the x value. Plug that into the equation?

Comment: For 45°, I got -1.45833 rad/min. -2.1875 for 60°. And -2.72129 for 75°. Are these the correct values?

Comment: I only checked the first one, and you are off by a sign error. I'm assuming it's because you used $\frac{dx}{dt} = 700$. However, if you consider what the change in $x$ is doing, it's actually decreasing the horizontal distance between the viewer and the plane, so $\frac{dx}{dt} = -700$.